# How to find the $ x,y$ coordinates of a point in between $2$ points in $3$ dimension

Tags: geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems

Point $1 = (0,0,0)$
Point $2 = (5,6,7)$

Given that point $3$ have a $z$-coordinate of $3$, how can I find the $x,y$ coordinates of point $3$?

Comment: Are all three points on the same line?

Comment: Yes, they are along the same line.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
All points between points $P_1$ and $P_2$ can be expressed as$$tP_1 + (1-t)P_2.$$

Comment: I sure am glad $\mathbb{R}^3$ is convex ;P